# Prettier - Atom editor replacing single quotes with double quotes

Tags: atom-editor, prettier

I am having an issue with prettier code formatter, It is replacing single quotes with the double quotes. Previously it was working very well but I updated the system and now having this issue. 
Here's my prettier configuration in `config.cson`

```
"prettier-atom":
    formatOnSaveOptions:
      respectEslintignore: false
      showInStatusBar: true
    prettierEslintOptions: {}
    prettierOptions:
      singleQuote: true
      trailingComma: "es5"
      useTabs: true
    useEslint: true
    useStylelint: true
```

and this is my `.prettierrc`

```
{
  "semi": false,
  "printWidth": 125,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "all"
}
```

Not sure whats went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had space to dig into this issue very deep but to restart atom with that config setup which you have can solve your problem. It worked for me.

[This link will be helpful](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-atom/issues/204)